# asp.net mvc 4 validation , comparing between two "System.TimeSpan" fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, validation

I am woking on asp.net MVC4 project 
I would like to know how to add validation for "Time Span "
I used Fluent Validation before 
ASP.NET MVC: LessThan and GreaterThan
I have added

```
[Required]
public System.TimeSpan Start_hr { get; set; }
[Required]
public System.TimeSpan End_hr { get; set; }
```

I used to http://foolproof.codeplex.com

```
[Required]
public  System.TimeSpan Start { get; set; }

[Required]
[GreaterThan("Start")]
public  System.TimeSpan End { get; set; }
```

but it doen't work with "System.TimeSpan"

Do you have any idea how to add validation to "System.TimeSpan" field

**UPDATE:**

Seems that  foolproof doesn't work with EF 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1752975.aspx/1